# Saving an array of elements (tags) on form validation fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have an form input which looks like this

[image: viz1]

And it's functionality is

```js
let tagArray = @json(old('tags') ?? []);

function convertToSlug(str) {
    str = str.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_\-+=\[\]{};:'"\\|\/,.<>?\s]/g, ' ')
            .toLowerCase();

    str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');

    str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-');   

    return str;
}

$("#addTagButton").on('click', function() {
    let tagVal = convertToSlug($("#addTagInput").val());

    $("#addTagInput").val(tagVal);

    if(! tagArray.includes(tagVal)) {

        if(tagVal == '') {
            alert('Invalid value');
            return false;
        }

        tagArray.push(tagVal);
        $("#addedTagsList").append(`<span class="badge bg-secondary d-flex rounded border-0 p-2"><span class="mr-3">` + tagVal + `</span> <i class="fa fa-times text-white ml-auto align-middle" id="tag-` + tagVal +`" role="button" onclick="removeTag('` + tagVal + `')"></i></span>`);
        $("#addTagInput").val('');
    } else {
        alert('This tag is already added!');
    }
});
```

And here is what's happening with the tags array when the whole form is being submitted:

It's adding an hidden input with the tags array contents so I can pass the tags to the backend.

```
$("#editPostForm").on('submit', function() {
    if(tagArray.length > 0 && tagArray !== undefined && tagArray !== null) {
        var newInput = $("<input>",{
            type:   "hidden",
            name:   "tags[]",
            value: tagArray
        });
        $(this).append(newInput);
    }
});
```

But notice the `let tagArray = @json(old('tags') ?? [])` which must keep the added tags on form validation fail. The problem is that when the form fails I'm getting as a response of `@json(old('tags') ?? [])`:

```
let tagArray = ["test,test-98"];
```

and that's not what I need. I need the tags as separate elements in the array. Why does `@json(old('tags'))` returns the array like that? How can I make this work?

My project is on **Laravel 9**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was returning the tags as a single field. I had to repeat the hidden field for each tag.

This way tags on the Laravel side will be an actual array and not a string

```
$("#editPostForm").on('submit', function() {
    if(tagArray.length > 0 && tagArray !== undefined && tagArray !== null) {
        var newInput = $("<input>",{
            type:   "hidden",
            name:   "tags[]",
            value: tagArray
        });
        $(this).append(newInput);
    }
})
```

to

```
$("#editPostForm").on('submit', function() {
    $thisform = $(this);
    if(tagArray.length > 0 && tagArray !== undefined && tagArray !== null) {
        tagArray.forEach(function(item) {
            var newInput = $("<input>",{
                type:   "hidden",
                name:   "tags[]",
                value: item
            });
            $thisform.append(newInput);
        });
    }
});
```